# Regex with phrase, space and any digit

Tags: regex

I'm not very experienced with regular expressions, but i need one which allows specific phrase, space, any digit and dot in this order.

Like this:

```
Theme 1.
Question 15.
```

and so on.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+\.$
```

Meaning

```
^            ->  start of phrase
[a-zA-Z]+    ->  specific phrase allow one or more upper or lower alphabets
\s           ->  followed by space
\d+          ->  followed by one or more degits
\.           ->  end with dot
$            ->  end of phrase
```

#### regex demo

Comment: Upper or lower alphabiotics?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex

```
\w+\s\d+.
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJLr4X/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for your needs

```
Theme \d+\.
Question \d+\.
```

The above examples check for Theme and Question as the specific phrase, followed by a space, then any digits and a .(dot).

If you don't want any specific phrase, you can use \w+ instead of the Theme and Question (`\w+ \d+\.`).

P.S: You can use https://regex101.com/ to play with regex online. This site also tells the meaning of all the expressions.